# coredata sqlite - adding records in an app update

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that uses coredata. The initial sqlite file that shipped with the application has about 500 records.

I need to provide an update that among several -none core data related- things, adds about 8 records to the database. The .sqlite file is in the Documents directory since in my persistentStoreCoordinator I access the file with:

```
NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *targetPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDB.sqlite"];
....
....
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/MyDB.sqlite"]];
```

In order to add the 8 records, can I use a utility such as **SQLite Database browser** and add the records with an index and whatever core data added there -- and then replace the old .sqlite file in the Document\ directory with the new one **without** having to go through core data versioning?

If not, are there anyways to do that without having to rely on versioning?

Comment: You can try that but better test whether it works because usually you can't add records to the sqlite database using normal sql tools without upsetting Core Data.  It might be safer to write some OS X code to add the records to the existing database, save it and then use this to replace the file shipped with the app.  However if you need to add the 8 records to users existing databases without loosing any of their data then best have some code to add the 8 records when the app starts with an existing store.

Comment: The user has no data and I don't mind writing code to generate the .sqlite file... However if I do that, will I be able to simply "replace" the existing .sqlite with the new one? No need for versioning or special handling?